# Компоненты по разные стороны LinearLayout

Tags: android, java

У меня есть `LinearLayout` и три компонента на нем. Как сделать вот такую компоновку?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если не заменять `LinearLayout` на `RelativeLayout`, то можно между B и C вставить еще один `View` такого вида:

```
<View
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

Вся магия заключается в `android:layout_weight="1"`. Благодаря этому атрибуту, `View` растянется на всю доступную ширину.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделать для b так:

```
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
```